# FTPS using Data Power

Tags: ftp

Here is my question

Currently we are communicating with a vendor using Data Power using FTPS
basically we drop in a file in a inbox of the vendor, and Data power on their side picks up the file

similarly they pick up the file, and drop back a response into our inbox

they were using a X IP to communicate for 2 years, now they have changed their external IP

all this while the firewall rule has been to allow communication from Client -> Vendor and not the other way around

after changing data power configuration to the new ip, we are not able to receive the files from vendor

when asked, the data power admin asks us to define another rule in firewall, which will allow vendor -> client as well

firewall team is putting up a fight for this

we being the application team , have no idea of either data power or firewall

we are not sure who is right

any comments please

Answer (score 0):

So, you have an existing firewall rule that allows their old external IP to come in and drop files via FTPS?

And you need to change that firewall rule since they changed their IP?

Sounds pretty straightforward. The firewall rule needs to be changed.

If the firewall team puts up a fight, point out that the existing rule is allowing an unknown entity inside as the intended endpoint is no longer at that IP.